# Expo + Nativewind Build error

Tags: expo

Estou tendo erro ao utilizar o `eas-cli` para gerar a apk do meu app utilizando o nativewind v4.

```
...
 "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "expo": "~50.0.11",
    "expo-blur": "~12.9.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.27.6",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.2",
    "firebase": "^10.9.0",
    "nativewind": "4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.12.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
...
```

[O erro que aparece no console do eas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM7z8.png)

Como manda a documentação estou importando o tailwindcss no arquivo `_layout.tsx` da raiz da `app/` e também já revisei todos arquivos de configuração e estão idênticos aos da documentação.

Alguem já teve esse problema e soube como resolver? Desde já agradeço